# On macOS, how do we remove the past commands history from Terminal > Shell > New Command?

Tags: command-line, terminal, zsh, command-history, macos

We want to remove the list of commands that were run in the past in the `New Command` window.

It is the AutoFill or AutoComplete history of commands.

---

To see them, follow these steps:

1. Launch `Terminal`
2. Open `Shell` menu, and click on `New Command`

If it is empty, type something and run it. The next time you open the `New Command`, you'll be able to see the prior commands because it is stored in the dropdown list of the `New Command` window.

---

Any idea on how to clear these?

[image: This history has to be erased]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run this command :

```
open -a Finder ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist
```

You'll see a CommandHistory tab where you can remove entries.

If com.apple.Terminal.plist is not in above path, you can search it by :

```
find ~ -name com.apple.Terminal.plist
```

Comment: A file by that name does not exist.

Comment: Do you have ~/Library/Preferences directory ? Does it contain com.apple.*.plist files ?

Comment: Yes, and yes. The directory exists, and so do those com.apple.*.plist files. But the specific file you referenced to be edited, that file does not exist.

Comment: First of all, I am sorry that I didn't run the command you originally posted because I proceeded to check if the file exists in that directory using Finder.

Second, after running the `find` command, I find that the file exists in the location you suggested, Home > Library > Preferences. But, using Finder to explore the directory, the file is not listed. This is bizarre.

Third, had to search for the bits to be deleted, but it did work. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, ran it. That is how we edited the file. The past commands list is gone now.

Answer (score 1):

On the user's folder in macOS Catalina, **.zsh_history** contains the entire list of commands invoked by that user.

You can find this file if you open the user's folder in *Finder* and press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to show/hide these type of hidden files (starting with dot).

Tools like [*Visual Studio Code*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac) allow these to be listed and edited directly in the user's folder without changing default listing preferences or invoking more commands in terminal.